# Question about regression with 2 groups (male, female)

Tags: regression

I have the following question
suppose I have a data for men and women separately, I would like to model them in one regression , in this case I will have an indicator variable for them, and have one linear regression with the other covariates like age, hight, weight , and my dependent variable in Y .

what is the difference if I have 2 regression line one for female and one for male, and having 1 regression model with indicator variable ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do separate regressions (called *stratifiying*) then you won't have a direct measure of the effect of sex (or its standard error, p value or CI) and you won't be able to include any interactions with sex.

Depending on your dependent variable, interactions between the other IVs and sex might be important and interesting.

Comment: There are lots of other consequences, too, like how the coefficients other than sex can differ between the stratified models, and can it turn be different from the single model even without interactions. But the ability to estimate the effect of sex, as you mention, is probably the most important thing.